# Vector bundles on $S^2$ up to isomorphism

Tags: vector-bundles

I've recently become acquainted with the notion of a vector bundle on a topological space. I'm interested in what the vector bundles are over $S^2$. Certainly, it admits the tangent bundle. Specifically, 1-dimensional and 2-dimensional ones would be good to know about. I haven't found much by Googling, and the question is basic.

I think $S^2$ has at least two ones?

Comment: For $\Bbb R^2,$ see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186145).

Comment: And for $S^2,$ [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1923402).

Comment: @AnneBauval I've seen the $S^2$ one, but it doesn't directly answer my question

Comment: @AnneBauval Hold on, I'm reading it more carefully.

Comment: @AnneBauval Amazing, thank you very much!

Comment: Ok then, I am voting to close for this duplicate [Understanding Vector Bundles Over Spheres](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1923402/understanding-vector-bundles-over-spheres)